# python ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. trying to check datetimes

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I am trying to compare time values with DateTime.

```
open_time = datetime.time(6,30,00)
close_time = datetime.time(13,00,00)
list_of_time = [data_S['hour']]
```

data_S is just a Pandas DataFrame and I am converting the hour column into a list.

list_of_time printed looks like this:

```
[0       04:00:00
1       04:01:00
2       04:02:00
3       04:03:00
4       04:04:00
          ...
1515    16:55:00
1516    16:56:00
1517    16:57:00
1518    16:58:00
1519    16:59:00
Name: hour, Length: 1520, dtype: object]
```

I have this for loop to check if the time in the list is less than open_time

```
for i in list_of_time:
    if i < open_time:
       print (I)
```

I am getting this error when I run the file and I do not understand what the error is telling me.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Where, exactly, do you see this error?  Which line of code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to be doing:

```
list_of_time = data_S['hour'].tolist()
```

When you fetch a pandas column like this, it isn't just a simple list of numbers.  `tolist` will do that.

Comment: I think this is right because the value error was saying they're trying to get a True or False from an ambigous case where Multiple instances of either could be possible.